# Pre-allocate disk space for an application

Tags: mfc, diskspace

My MFC based application would write multiple files of different types on a disk. I have to pre-allocate fixed disk space for the entire application so that other applications do not eat up my disk resources. Through google, I figured out how to pre-allocate disk space for a single file but not for multiple files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this answer [Reserve disk space before writing a file for efficiency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356736/reserve-disk-space-before-writing-a-file-for-efficiency)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to pre-allocate disk space at application level (i.e. pre-allocate a chunk of space for multiple files). You have to allocate space for each file separately using `CFile::Seek` or `SetFilePointer`.