# Check if there is sufficient disk space to save a file; reserve it

Tags: c++, linux, file-io

I'm writing a C++ program which will be printing out large (2-4GB) files.

I'd like to make sure that there's sufficient space on the drive to save the files *before* I start writing them. If possible, I'd like to reserve this space.

This is taking place on a Linux-based system.

Any thoughts on a good way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at [`posix_fallocate()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/posix_fallocate):

```
NAME
       posix_fallocate - allocate file space

SYNOPSIS

       int posix_fallocate(int fd, off_t offset, off_t len);

DESCRIPTION
       The function posix_fallocate() ensures that disk space is allocated for
       the file referred to by the descriptor fd for the bytes  in  the  range
       starting  at  offset  and continuing for len bytes.  After a successful
       call to posix_fallocate(), subsequent writes to bytes in the  specified
       range are guaranteed not to fail because of lack of disk space.
```

**edit** In the comments you indicate that you use C++ streams to write to the file. As far as I know, there's no standard way to get the file descriptor (`fd`) from a `std::fstream`.

With this in mind, I would make disk space pre-allocation a separate step in the process. It would:

1. [`open()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open) the file;
2. use [`posix_fallocate()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/posix_fallocate);
3. [`close()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/close) the file.

This can be turned into a short function to be called before you even open the `fstream`.

Comment: This looks like a C-style function. Thoughts on how to mix it with C++ stream operators?

Comment: @Richard: You could try to get the `fd` out of the `ostream`, but AFAIK there's no standard way to do this. I personally would just `open()` the file, use `posix_fallocate()` and `close()` it. Then you can use C++ I/O to re-open it, write the contents etc.

Comment: You could also write your own streambuf to wrap low-level `read()` and `write()` calls, if you need to be sure nobody replaces the file under you. But reopening is probably easier.

Comment: @aix, that's a cunning solution and I like it! But, I seem to recall, from somewhere, that when you open a file for output its length gets trimmed to zero first. (My testing confirmed this.) I think some additional trick is needed. :-/

Comment: @Richard: Specify `ios::in | ios::out` as the second argument to the `ofstream`'s constructor, and the file will not get truncated.

Answer (score 1):

Use aix's answer (`posix_fallocate()`), but since you're using C++ streams, you'll need a bit of a hack to get the stream's file descriptor.

For that, use the code here: http://www.ginac.de/~kreckel/fileno/.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **C++ 17**, you should do it with `std::filesystem::resize_file`

As [shown in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58824755/9007125)